# writing binary data with tobytes() can not be read with software on Windows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binary, point-clouds

I am trying to write some xyz point data to a .ply file using python.

I am using [this](https://github.com/philwilkes/treeseg/blob/master/python/ply_io.py) script here which basically writes a pandas DataFrame to a binary format via a recarry and numpy method `tobytes()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pc = pd.read_csv('points.txt')

with open('some_file.ply', 'w') as ply:

    ply.write("ply\n")
    ply.write('format binary_little_endian 1.0\n')
    ply.write("comment Author: Phil Wilkes\n")
    ply.write("obj_info generated with pcd2ply.py\n")
    ply.write("element vertex {}\n".format(len(pc)))
    ply.write("property float x\n")
    ply.write("property float y\n")
    ply.write("property float z\n")
    ply.write("end_header\n")

    pc[['x', 'y', 'z']] = pc[['x', 'y', 'z']].astype('f4')

    ply.write(pc[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_records(index=False).tobytes())
```

This script works fine on my Mac and software like CloudCompare can read it; however, when I use the same script on a windows machine CloudCompare can read the header info but garbels the binary content.

When I read the a text file version into CloudCompare and output as a binary file both Linux and Windows versions can read it but the file contents are different.

[Here](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfaptv/made_with_code.ply) is the version that is produced by the above script, [here](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfaptv/made_with_windows.ply) is the version produce by CloudCompare on Windows and [here](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfaptv/points.txt) is the raw data.

Comment: How is it using list as an index? Is `pc` some custom type that does undercover manipulation with index values?

Comment: I have updated code to a complete example, using the data from the download. `pc` is a pandas DataFrame, the list indexes columns in `pc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify what line ending to use when opening the file:

```
open(output_name, 'w', newline='\n')
```

After rewriting for Python 3 the file has to be written to twice - once for the header and once for the binary component so the new function looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pc = pd.read_csv('points.txt')

with open(output_name, 'w', newline='\n') as ply:

    ply.write("ply\n")
    ply.write('format binary_little_endian 1.0\n')
    ply.write("comment Author: Phil Wilkes\n")
    ply.write("obj_info generated with pcd2ply.py\n")
    ply.write("element vertex {}\n".format(len(pc)))
    ply.write("property float x\n")
    ply.write("property float y\n")
    ply.write("property float z\n")
    ply.write("end_header\n")

with open(output_name, 'ab') as ply:
    pc[['x', 'y', 'z']] = pc[['x', 'y', 'z']].astype('f4')
    ply.write(pc[cols].to_records(index=False).tobytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `made_with_code.ply` and `made_with_windows.ply` is that in the latter, all decimals are rounded to 2 decimals as you can see with:

```
with open('windows.ply', 'rb') as f:
    np.core.records.fromfile(f, formats='f4,f4,f4,f4')
```

after extraction of the data part with `tail -c +274 made_with_windows.ply > windows.ply`.

The following code produces a file identical (in the data part) to `made_with_windows.ply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pc = pd.read_csv('points.txt')

with open('made_with_code_new.ply', 'wb') as ply:
    ply.write("ply\n")
    ply.write('format binary_little_endian 1.0\n')
    ply.write("comment Author: Phil Wilkes\n")
    ply.write("obj_info generated with pcd2ply.py\n")
    ply.write("element vertex {}\n".format(len(pc)))
    ply.write("property float x\n")
    ply.write("property float y\n")
    ply.write("property float z\n")
    ply.write("end_header\n")

    pc[['x', 'y', 'z', 'n']] = pc[['x', 'y', 'z', 'n']].round(2).astype('f4')

    ply.write(pc[['x', 'y', 'z', 'n']].to_records(index=False).tobytes())
```